# Avoid the View being loaded from the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I avoid a View being loaded using the cache ?

I tried putting the `[OutputCache(Duration = 1)]` before my method that returns the View through a `ActionResult` but without success.

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 1)]
    public ActionResult Receita(string id, string periodo)
    {
        // Do my stuff

        var receita = new ReceitaAssunto()
        {
            // More stuff
        };

        return View(receita);
    }
```

When I pass a new value through the method's parameter, should exhibit this values in my View, but it haven't had refresh, always exhibit the old ones.

**View**

```
@model Dashboard.Domain.ClasseTipada.ReceitaAssunto

<ul class="list-group clear-list m-t">

@{
     var i = 1;
     foreach(var elemento in Model.ReceitaPorTipoReceita)
     {
        <li class="list-group-item fist-item">
            <span class="pull-right">
                <span id="txtTextoValorLocacao">@elemento.Valor.ToString("C", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"))</span>
                </span>
                <span class="label label-success">@i</span>@elemento.DescricaoOrigem
        </li>
        i++;
      }
      i = 0;
 }
 </ul>
```

**UPDATE**

I saw the request using Firebug and the result it's exactly what I want, but it doesn't render in my View.

[image]

**How I saw (take a look at the values), these values it's true only in the first page load**

[image]

**JS**

```
    $("#btnTrimestral").on("click", function () {           
        GeradorGrafico.URLJson = "@Url.Action("Receita", new { periodo = "trimestral" })";
        GeradorGrafico.init();
    });
```

Comment: can you show your ajax call

Comment: Are you trying to disable cache completely for the `Receita` action or just want the cached copy to vary by param?

Comment: @haim770 A better explanation: I have 4 buttons (Monthly, 
quarterly, semiannual, anual). When I click in each button, will pass a new value through parameter to my method. So, my Receita View shouldn't cache these values

Comment: So you basically need the cached copy to vary by param?

Comment: Yes, but I made some tests here, and I got what I want through JS, but it's weird because in my view I have the foreach and it works fine, just don't render the new value on the screen

Answer (score 0):

put it into Global.asax.cs in `Application_BeginRequest().`

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: It didn't work, and I double check what it's passing through the receita object and thats right, with the new values.

Comment: which browswer are you using/.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 32.0.1

Comment: okk as your data is already cached by the browser it is showing the cached one...just clear your chache and you'll not have this problem again...also clean and rebuild the solution again

Comment: Did it, clean the browser's cache, rebuild solution, but still the same thing.

Comment: clean your solution also

Comment: I did all the steps over again, Delete browser's cookie/cache, Rebuild solution, clea solution, but stills the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61432/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-lucas-santos).